# how to create nodes in neo4j using python, only with unique edges/relations while doing bulk insert from .data file?

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, cypher

My data looks like this: (it's a .data file)

```
emp_id          cus_id
bckshfow2424       dsf31
bckshfow2424       dsf31
bckshfow2424       dsf31
bckshdw2424        dsbd1
bckshdw2424        dsbd1
bckshdw2424        dsf31
```

for the above set of combination, I would want to create the nodes having unique relations expecting a resulting dataset of:

```
emp_id   cus_id
bckshfow2424    dsf31
bckshdw2424     dsbd1
bckshdw2424      dsf31
```

like this have a bunch of records in the data file with some of the dups.
I am using the following command to load the data. However, I am not able to load the unique combination nodes:

```
with open("file_path") as f:
next(f)
with driver.session() as session:
    for line in f:
        a = line.split('\t')
        print a
        result = session.run(
            "MERGE (e:Empid {id:'" + a[1] + "' }) MERGE  (c:Custid { id: '" + a[2] + "'})  CREATE UNIQUE (e)-[m:HAS]->(c) ;")
        print a
```

After loading the data..when I run: 
    MATCH (e:Empid) RETURN COUNT (e);
I get 2.

And the query to get count of existing relationship gives me result as 5 which is the original dataset with dups.
    MATCH (e:Empid) -[m:HAS]->(c:Custid)
    With type(m) as count_m
    Return count_m;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should use p**arameter in your queries**, instead of creating a dynamic string query. It will be faster.

Otherwise, you should not use `CREATE UNIQUE`, it's deprecated. Can you replace it by a `MERGE` and test it ?

Comment: It worked! However I feel HTTP protocol is much simpler way to load.. thanks for your response!!